# IIS 7.5 - перенаправление с одного домена на другой, с сохранением путей

Tags: redirect, iis, rewrite

У меня есть сайт, который открывается с разных доменов (site.domain.eu и site.domain.ru). Мне необходимо создать правило, которое перенаправит весь трафик с site.domain.ru на site.domain.eu, с сохранением путей, т.е. ссылки типа site.domain.ru/page1?=test должны так же перенаправиться на site.domain.eu/page1?=test. Подскажите пожалуйста решение этого ребуса? Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал небольшую заглушку, лучше не получается

```
<rule name="redirect .ru to .eu" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^site.domain\.ru" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://site.domain.eu/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```